# How to capture multiple monitors using screen in VLC on Mac

Tags: ubuntu, mac, vlc-media-player

I am trying to use VLC from the command line to record the screen. When the laptop is connected to another display (in extended mode), that is when I face issues.

On ubuntu, the screen module captures both the displays in the same file. However on Mac, it seems it is impossible to capture the second screen along with the first one.

I notice that the Desktop app on Ubuntu has option to capture the desktop, and when I do this, it records both the screens. However, on Mac, VLC allows you to choose only one screen.

Is it even possible to record both the screens at once for MacOSX?

=====EDIT========

Command I am using

```
/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -I rc screen:// --sout-keep --screen-fps=7.0 --sout #transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=1500,acodec=mp3,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=/home/shashi/temp/temp.mp4,no-overwrite}
```

Comment: What commands are you actually using for the recording?

Comment: I added the command I am using..